# Understanding the solution of a problem

Tags: combinatorics

Recently I have found the following problem related to inclusion-exclusion as an example in a book .Since the problem is used as an example it’s solution is given in that book. I can’t understand some portion of the solution.Can anyone explain the portion I can’t understand. What  I can’t understand is stated below. Firstly I stated the problem and it’s solution and then stated what  I can’t understand.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please see **Stars and Bars**, in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

We want to find $|A_1|$, which is the number of nonnegative integer solutions to the equation $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=12$ subject to the condition $y_1 \ge 5$.  Since the first term in the left hand side must be at least 5, we can rewrite the equation as $y_1' +y_2+y_3+y_4=7$, where each term in the left hand side must be nonnegative (so the condition $y_1 \ge 5$ is now replaced by $y_1' \ge 0$).  The number of solutions to this equation is the number of ways to arrange 7 identical stars and 3 identical separator bars, which is ${10 \choose 7}$.

Similarly, $|A_1 \cap A_2|$ is the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $y_1'+y_2'+y_3+y_4 = (12-5-4)$. The number of solutions is ${6 \choose 3}$.   The other terms can be computed similarly.